# jquery ui dialog scroll bars

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, dialog

Im using the jquery UI Dialog. (modal)

In Firefox and Chrome it looks fine. in IE8 scroll bars appear.
how can i remove them?

Comment: is your content bigger than the modal area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting overflow:none on the dialog fixed it.

Comment: Where did you set this?  css?

Comment: How come it fixed it if overflow:none is not a valid value for overflow? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp
Was it hidden instead?

Answer (score 0):

Because of small rendering differences, IE usually needs a little more space. Increase width/height a little bit and see, if the scrollbars disappear.